# SQL data precedence in CASE statements

Tags: sql, types, floating-point, case, decimal

This is kind of a silly question, but can someone explain how SQL handles different numerical data types in case statements?

For example, what happens to the following if `t.val` is a `float` data type?

```
CASE 
    WHEN t.val > 0 
        THEN CAST(t.val AS decimal) 
    ELSE t.val 
END
```

My understanding is that a column can only be one data type. SQL seemingly allows for this code to pass through the interpreter. What data type can we expect in the result set with that case statement?

Comment: "What data type can we expect in the result set with that case statement?" - not what you might expect! Try it yourself .....  You should always perform an explicit CAST() to avoid surprises

Comment: Also - `CASE` is an **expression** (that returns a single, atomic value) - not a "statement" ...

Comment: When in doubt consult the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16